# JSON.decode issue

Tags: json, actionscript-3

I found an old MMO game I had been working on with a friend some years ago, but when running the bellow code (from a bigger file) it just keeps throwing:

**RoomManager.as(43): col: 14 Error: Access of undefined property JSON.**

```
public function RoomManager(_con:Connection, _rmap:String = null, _rwarps:String = null)
    {
        _connection = _con;
        roomMap = JSON.decode (_rmap) as Array;
        if(_rwarps != null && _rwarps != "") roomWarps = JSON.decode (_rwarps) as Array;
        ObjectManager.connection = _con;
    }
```

I have been unable to find anything to give me some detail to further explore the issue, can anyone advise what to look at?

Thanks

Comment: [`JSON`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/JSON.html) is available in Flash Player 11+, for older targets you have to use [as3corelib](https://github.com/mikechambers/as3corelib)

Comment: I am using the lib you linked to

Comment: Are you importing it in `RoomManager`?

Comment: It is imported yeah, didn't include whole file as hundreds if lines

Comment: If so, try placing fully qualified path to "JSON" in place of anything. It's possible you've got an ambiguous reference. Or it's possible that you have a variable `JSON` elsewhere, thus your code queries the variable which is null in turn.

Comment: To @Vesper's point, try removing the `import` and target Flash Player 11+.

Comment: im targeting flash 20, removing the import then throws an error with the decode `JSON.decode`

Comment: What error does it throw?

Comment: n.b. Using the built-in JSON from FP 11+, you need to call `JSON.parse()`.

Comment: @Brian using `JSON.parse` then throws **[Fault] exception, information=SyntaxError: Error #1132: Invalid JSON parse input.** with the JSON import removed, with it included throws **RoomManager.as(43): col: 14 Error: Access of undefined property JSON.**   

`public function RoomManager(_con:Connection, _rmap:String = null, _rwarps:String = null)
  {
   _connection = _con;
   roomMap = JSON.parse(_rmap) as Array;
   if(_rwarps != null && _rwarps != "") roomWarps = JSON.parse(_rwarps) as Array;
   ObjectManager.connection = _con;
  }`

Comment: Got it working, sorry @Aaron I missed your comment!  If one of you answers, as both required to get it working then I'll mark correct.  thanks guys

Comment: @SaucedApples Edit that into the question.  Code posted in comments is hard to parse.

Comment: Post as answer and I'll accept.  Thank you